# Get incoming connection's TTL value in Golang

Tags: go, networking, tcp, connection, ip

We have a project that provides a ping like functionality for TCP connections named `tcping` which offers some comprehensive reporting. Lately, we've been wanting to add an additional feature in which we would also show the **incoming** probe's **TTL**.

I did some digging into Go's `net` package and `golang.org/x/net/ipv4` and apparently it is possible to get the **outgoing** TTL but not the **incoming** TTL value from a `net.Conn` type which is quite surprising.

Now, it is feasible that I have missed something. I would really appreciate it if anyone could show me a way to get the incoming connection's TTL or at least confirm that it is not feasible.

you can view the responsible function for making connections [here](https://github.com/pouriyajamshidi/tcping/blob/9a713aa9bdf7aab16410ea9fc06be0a854d40440/tcping.go#L761-L787) and the entire source code [here](https://github.com/pouriyajamshidi/tcping)

I have read through the Golang's net and net/ipv4 packages as well as searching the web. I am able to get the connection's outgoing TTL but not the incoming TTL from `net.Conn` type

Comment: A connection doesn’t have a ttl, and the tcp interface doesn’t expose individual packets. Can you explain what you are trying to do in terms of the underlying socket api?

Comment: TTL is an IPv4 thing (in the IPv4 header and consumed prior to the segment being passed to TCP), and it has nothing to do with TCP, which is unaware of any such thing. IPv6 has eliminated the TTL in favor of Hop Count, so there is no TTL for TCP segments carried by IPv6.

Comment: @JimB Just wanted to get and display the incoming pakcet's TTL.

Comment: @RonMaupin I understand what TTL and hop limit are and where in the stack they belong to. My question is how to get the incoming packet's TTL in Go and display it; if possible at all

Comment: You are asking about the TTL of a TCP connection, and there is no such thing, The TTL is in the IPv4 header, and each IP packet may take a different route, even those that carry segments of the same connection, because each IP packet is routed individually by each router in the path without regard to any other packet that may have come before, so each packet carrying a TCP segment for the same TCP connection may have a different TTL at the destination. You cannot say that TCP connection W:X:Y:Z has any particular TTL; it just does not make sense.

Comment: @RonMaupin Fair enough. It seems like you might have been caught up in a TTL tangle, but let's not lose sight of the main issue here. The challenge isn't about mixing up OSI with your favorite dipping sauce, but rather about the quest for that incoming TTL value. If you take a closer look at the question, you'll notice we're not lost in the land of networking layers; we're on a TTL treasure hunt! So, while each packet might be on its own TTL adventure, any insights into fetching that incoming TTL would be the real MVP here.

Comment: You need to get it from IP. That is the point. TCP and its connections have no idea about TTL.

Comment: @RonMaupin, Right. I am seeking help here to do that.